# dynamic size of a uilabel

Tags: height, uilabel

I have uilabel and this uilabel should grow in rows depending on the length of the text. Anyway I don't know how to do it. I already searched for different solution on the net but did not find anything that works as i want. currently I'm doing this here:

```
size_label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
size_label.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 180, 10000);
size_label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
size_label.text = some_long_text;
size_label.numberOfLines = 10000;
[size_label sizeToFit];
NSLog(@"size_label.frame.size.height = %f", size_label.frame.size.height );
```

The result of NSLog is always 19. This is not what I want because the text would a least require like 150 pixels.

How do I get depending on:

1. width of the uilabel (width must not change)
2. text length and uifont

the

1. number of rows
2. the height of the uilabel

such that everything is shown and the text just fits fine.

Answer (score 1):

Foll code might help to autosize label

```
UILabel *size_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 180.0, 40.0);
size_label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
size_label.text = some_long_text;
size_label.numberOfLines = 0;

[size_label sizeToFit];
```